# How to insert math with curly brackets into tikz decoration text along path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I was going to write along an arc some math expression with curly brackets.
Somehow the following snippet causes pdflatex to freeze.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->,blue,
 postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, raise=4pt,
  text={ $\{ hello \}${} },text color=blue,
 text align={align=center}}}] (0,5) arc (90:0:5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I do it otherwise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to do is to use `{$\lbrace$}` and the corresponding `{$\rbrace$}`:

```
text={{$\lbrace$}hello{$\rbrace$}}
```

which yields:

[image]

Alternatively you could use:

```
text={{\textbraceleft}hello{\textbraceright}}
```

### Notes:

- Note the additional set of braces.
- The TikZ/PGF manual states for text deocrations:

  > - Each character in the text is typeset in a separate \hbox...
  >
  >   ...
  > - It is only possible to typeset text in math mode under considerable restrictions. Math mode is entered and exited using any character of category code 3 (e.g., in plain TEX this is $). Math subscripts and superscripts need to be contained within braces (e.g., `{^y_i}`) as do commands like `\times` or `\cdot`. However, even modestly complex mathematical typesetting is unlikely to be successful along a path (or even desirable).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[->,blue,
 postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, raise=4pt,
  text={{$\lbrace$}hello{$\rbrace$}},text color=blue,
 text align={align=center}}}] (0,5) arc (90:0:5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### Bizarre Behavior:

Using `text={$hello$}`, I get:

[image]

Comment: I noticed that bizarre behavior too. You can prevent it by adding {} after $.

Comment: @mlt Thanks, I was currently stuck with that same problem. Has this ever been reported as a bug in TikZ?

Comment: Also worth noting: if you want to use a macro inside the math text (within the decoration), you will need an extra pair of brackets encompassing that macro. For example: `decoration={text along path, text align=center, text={${\overline{s}}${}}, raise=18pt}`

Comment: Another note on the bizarre behavior: adding a subscript to the math can throw an error (e.g. `{$T_r${}}`). Instead, try: `{{$T_r$}{}}`.

Comment: @RicoPicone: Interesting. Seems that using math mode is a real issue, but at least there are workarounds that allow you to achieve the desired functionality.