# PGFPlots: Math, commands and braces in text along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, decorations

Following my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237456/pgfplots-plot-text-along-function) about how to plot a text along a path another question came up. How can I add math or commands with `\command` to the text along the path?

This here works:

`postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\scriptsize| Loading}}}`

These do not:

`postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\scriptsize| 0\textdegree Loading}}}`

`postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\scriptsize| 0$^{\circ}$ Loading}}}`

I tried capsulating the commands and math with braces but this doesn't work either. No error is produced, just the compilation with `pdflatex` takes forever and doesn't end.

Can someone tell me why this does not work and how to fix that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:2,
    xmin=0, xmax=2.25,
    ymin=0, ymax=4.5,
    samples=100,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
]
\addplot+[mark=none,samples=150] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)};
\addplot[draw=none,
      postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
          text={|\scriptsize| Loading},raise=1ex,
          text align={center}
      }},
      domain=0.5:1.5,] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)+0.5};
\addplot+[mark=none,black,domain=0.5:1.5,->,,samples=150] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)+0.5};
\addplot[draw=none,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
          text={|\scriptsize| Unloading},raise=-2ex,
          text align={center},
      }},
      domain=0.5:1.5] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)-0.5};
    \addplot+[<-,mark=none, black,domain=0.5:1.5,samples=150] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)-0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Math in decorations seems to be delicate, as discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75256/how-to-insert-math-with-curly-brackets-into-tikz-decoration-text-along-path.  Don't know about `\textdegree`, but maybe the problem is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a unit, I would use `siunitx` :

```
\addplot[draw=none,
      postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
          text={|\scriptsize| {\SI{0}{\degree}} Loading},raise=1ex,
          text align={center}
      }},
      domain=0.5:1.5,] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)+0.5};
```

Full code will be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:2,
    xmin=0, xmax=2.25,
    ymin=0, ymax=4.5,
    samples=100,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
]
\addplot+[mark=none,samples=150] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)};
\addplot[draw=none,
      postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
          text={|\scriptsize| {\SI{0}{\degree}} Loading},raise=1ex,
          text align={center}
      }},
      domain=0.5:1.5,] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)+0.5};
\addplot+[mark=none,black,domain=0.5:1.5,->,,samples=150] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)+0.5};
\addplot[draw=none,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
          text={|\scriptsize| {\SI{0}{\degree}} Unloading},raise=-2ex,
          text align={center},
      }},
      domain=0.5:1.5] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)-0.5};
    \addplot+[<-,mark=none, black,domain=0.5:1.5,samples=150] {2*0.7*(1+x)*(1-1/(1+x)^3)-0.5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that we have to hide the `\SI{0}{\degree}` from tikz parser by using braces.

[image]

Comment: Thx once again @Harish Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @jarauth the link helped me to find the trick. I must have somehow missed that during my tests with brackets.

This here works like a charm:

`postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text={|\scriptsize| 0{\textdegree} Loading}}}`