# How to connect points on a circle with arcs and label them

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I have a "circle" or a circular region. I want some nodes on the circular region to be connected by the arcs. and I also want some nodes (like \hdots) to appear very close on the circle. and the remaining circle should not have any line width. I would like to change the radius of the circle and also the thickness of the arcs and the size of the nodes. I finally want to label my nodes. I am not even sure not even sure how to google for this. I will appreciate any links that can guide me to a resource which can help me draw this.

[image]

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447332/tikz-curved-label-for-arc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quite basic solution but maybe it can help:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node{+};
  \draw (2,0) node{$\cdot$} node[right]{$\alpha$};
  \draw (2,0) arc (0:30:2) node{$\cdot$} node[right]{$\beta$} ;
  \draw (45:2) node{$\cdot$} node[right, above]{$\gamma$} arc (45:90:2) node{$\cdot$} node[above]{$\delta$} ;
    \draw[dashed] (105:2) arc (105:345:2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]